# I created a branch off of the wrong branch in git and already merged the old branch into master, how do I remove the commits from the other branch?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

When I created a branch, I accidentally created it off of an experimental branch which I do not want any of those changes commited to our SVN repository.  The branch that I created was already merged into master and the old branch discarded.  I just realized what I was about to commit prior to running git svn dcommit.

How can I commit the single commit from the original branch?  I have singled it out in git log.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a situation like:

```
x--x--x--x--x1--------m--y--y (master)
    \                /
     \              /
      -o--o--o--z--z (deleted)
```

You could:

- make a `tmp` branch, tag `m` and reset to x1
- use `git reflog` to get the HEAD of the deleted branch 'br' and create a branch 'br' on it, and tag o1 (the latest 'old' commits before your experimental commits)

```
              [tagM]
                -m--y--y (tmp)
               /
              /
x--x--x--x--x1  (master)
    \                
     \              
      -o--o--o1--z--z (br)
            [tagO]
```

- git checkout br && git rebase --onto master o1

```
              [tagM]
                   -m--y--y (tmp)
                  /
                 /
x--x--x--x------x1  (master)
    \            \            
     \            \    
      -o--o--o1    z--z (br)
            [tagO]
```

- merge only the commits you want to master: `git checkout master && git merge br`

```
                [tagM]
                   -m--y--y (tmp)
                  /
                 /
x--x--x--x------x1--------m2  (master)
    \            \       /      
     \            \     /
      -o--o--o1    z'--z' (br)
            [tagO]
```

- rebase the other commits done since the initial merge on top of `master`.

```
                [tagM]
                   -m
                  /
                 /
x--x--x--x------x1--------m2--y'--y'  (master,tmp)
    \            \       /      
     \            \     /
      -o--o--o1    z'--z' (br)
            [tagO]
```

- `git checkout tmp && git rebase --onto master tagM && git merge master`
  (fast forward merge)